# Interpolating 360 degree Images out of only 8 images that are 45 degrees apart

Tags: image, image-processing, 360-degrees

Sony has demonstrated a very nice technology in Siggraph 2010 where an object can be displayed on a "round LCD" so it could be visible from all directions in 3D without the use of special glasses.

This is very nice but in the demonstration movie I saw something that caught my eye. In order to display a 360 degree image they have to generate 360 images (one degree apart) of the object they want to show. Sony are able to interpolate 360 images from only 8 (45 degrees apart).

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6BFKC-NKRFw&feature=player_embedded#!

I was looking allot for such mothod/algorithem and I would be very happy to know if there is a paper on the subject. Anyone?

http://www.engadget.com/2010/07/28/sonys-360-degree-raymodeler-3d-display-brings-its-glasses-free/

Thanks.

Gilad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This movie is *extremely* deceptive about what is going on. The Sony RayModeler is not an 'autostereoscopic' display, it's a full volumetric display generated by a high-speed rotating LED array. The device requires all 360 images, there is no interpolation from 8 images to 360 happening in the device.

The 8 cameras business is just a standard passive multiview stereo setup that is separate from the RayModeler. There are literally hundreds of papers on the topic, see http://vision.middlebury.edu/mview/

If you wanted to solve the problem you described though, it's called "light field interpolation" and you can read about it in this paper by Atalay and Mount, http://www.cs.umd.edu/~mount/Projects/InterpOLF/ijcga.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Why do you look at their Siggraph paper ? You should find explanation and pointers to other papers with similar work.

Comment: That was my question, if anybody know of such paper (academic) or algorithm/method.

Comment: I try but didn't find their paper. The way I would do it : build a 3D model of the object from these 8 cameras and then project the 3D point on any plane (i.e. camera) you want. Since they are showing it in 3D they will anyway need the 3D model.

Comment: I thought about that for quite a while. It is not so easy building a 3D module and then project it. The images doesn't look very synthetic and real enough. In Sony's presentation, their images look very very good, no chance it is 3D based.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's an accident that the most impressive images were the ones generated by artificial 3D models.

The interpolation between the 45 degree cameras could be done by doing a perspective correction to account for the interpolated camera position. The hard part would be to blend the resulting images; for example the image at 22 degrees would need to blend in nearly equal amounts the perspective corrected images from the 0 degree camera and the 45 degree camera.